# Efficiently write one output file when partitioning by column

Tags: apache-spark, partitioning, parquet

I have a large data set, `df`, made up of events. I want to write it out, partitioned by year/month/dat/hour, and have each resulting partition contain only file.

Here's a code snippet:

```
df.partitionBy("event_year", "event_month", "event_day", "event_hour").
    mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).
    parquet(s"${output_data_root}/tmp/")
```

What's unclear is what to do with `df` prior to this operation to get one file out, as it's unclear how `partition(COL)` and `coalesce` interact. IE, what happens when I do:

```
df.repartition(col("year"), col("month"), col("day"), col("event_hour")).coalesce(1)
```

(or vice versa)

It wouldn't work to just `coalesce(1)` (the data set is far too large), but from what I can tell, `repartition(COL)` will not necessarily result in one partition per column set.

Answer (score 0):

It's still unclear to me exactly what is going on under the hood, but it turns out you just:

```
df.repartition(1, col("year"), col("month"), col("day"), col("event_hour"))
```

Anecdotally, this is WAY faster than `repartition(...).coalesce`, and particularly when using S3, it definitely is important to keep your file count minimal.